# Using Multiple Threads in Java To Shorten Program Time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I do not have much experience making multi-threaded applications but I feel like my program is at a point where it may benefit from having multiple threads. I am doing a larger scale project that involves using a classifier (as in machine learning) to classify roughly 32000 customers. I have debugged the program and discovered that it takes about a second to classify each user. So in other words this would take 8.8 hours to complete!

Is there any way that I can run 4 threads handling 8000 users each? The first thread would handle 1-8000, the second 8001-16000, the third 16001-23000, the fourth 23001-32000. Also, as of now each classification is done by calling a static function from another class...

Then when the other threads besides the main one should end. Is something like this feasible? If so, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide tips or steps on how to do this. I am familiar with the idea of critical sections (wait/signal) but have little experience with it.

Again, any help would be very much appreciated! Tips and suggestions on how to handle a situation like this are welcomed! Not sure it matters but I have a Core 2 Duo PC with a 2.53 GHZ processor speed.

Comment: You will not decrease your computation time at all by implementing what you described above.

Comment: If your work is entirely CPU-bound, your level of effective parallelism will be strictly limited to the number of CPU cores.

Comment: Make sure that any shared state is thread-safe.  Better yet, get rid of any shared state.

Comment: Okay I was unsure whether this would actually work or not. That is why I asked it here. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Short answer: yes. Real answer: the difficulty of doing it depends on the thread _safety_ of what you are doing. See `ForkJoinPool` in Java 7 and `Stream`s in Java 8 (or MapReduce as a general concept based on how you described your problem). One thing: it probably doesn't matter which thread is handling which customer (e.g., blocks don't really matter as long as they get done).

Comment: A good place to read up is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ Please note that multithreading can be very tricky and there's lots of hidden gotchas that can be a pain to debug (deadlock, live lock, race conditions, etc...)  Be VERY careful with how you manage state (connections, shared objects, locks, etc...).

Comment: I will definitely look into these two concepts you mentioned in Java 7 & 8. When it comes to multi threading I don't have that much knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: May be you can optimize your algorithm further before going for parallelism.

Comment: Your CPU has only 2 threads, running 4 threads on it won't increase much performance. The number of threads is often equal to the CPU's number of thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too lightweight for Apache Hadoop, which requires around 64MB chunks of data per server... but.. it's a perfect opportunity for Akka Actors, and, it just happens to support Java!

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.4/java/untyped-actors.html

Basically, you can have 4 actors doing the work, and as they finish classifying a user, or probably better, a number of users, they either pass it to a "receiver" actor, that puts the info into a data structure or a file for output, or, you can do concurrent I/O by having each write to a file on their own.. then the files can be examined/combined when they're all done.

If you want to get even more fancy/powerful, you can put the actors on remote servers.  It's still really easy to communicate with them, and you'd be leveraging the CPU/resources of multiple servers.

I wrote an article myself on Akka actors, but it's in Scala, so I'll spare you that.  But if you google "akka actors", you'll get lots of hand-holding examples on how to use it.  Be brave, dive right in and experiment.  The "actor system" is such an easy concept to pick up.  I know you can do it!

Comment: Wow, that sounds completely amazing! I've heard of Hadoop before from a database class awhile back but Akka actors sounds very promising. I will dive into this. I am sure that I'll learn a lot of useful things in the process too. Thanks again to you and everyone else that responded!

Answer (score 1):

Split the data up into objects that implement Runnable, then pass them to new threads.

Having more than four threads in this case won't kill you, but you cannot get more parallel work than you have cores (as mentioned in the comments) - if there are more threads than cores the system will have to handle who gets to go when.

If I had a class customer, and I want to issue a thread to prioritize 8000 customers of a greater collection I might do something like this:

```
public class CustomerClassifier implements Runnable {

  private customer[] customers;

  public CustomerClassifier(customer[] customers) {
     this.customers = customers;
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (int i=0; i< customers.length; i++) {
      classify(customer);//critical that this classify function does not
                         //attempt to modify a resource outside this class
                         //unless it handles locking, or is talking to a database
                         //or something that won't throw fits about resource locking
    }
  }  
}
```

then to issue these threads elsewhere

```
int jobSize = 8000;
customer[] customers = new customer[jobSize]();
int j = 0;
for (int i =0; i+j< fullCustomerArray.length; i++) {
  if (i == jobSize-1) {
    new Thread(new CustomerClassifier(customers)).start();//run will be invoked by thread
    customers = new Customer[jobSize]();
    j += i;
    i = 0;
  }
  customers[i] = fullCustomerArray[i+j];
}
```

If you have your classify method affect the same resource somewhere you will have to 
 implement locking and will also kill off your advantage gained to some degree.

Concurrency is extremely complicated and requires a lot of thought, I also recommend looking at the oracle docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html
(I know links are bad, but hopefully the oracle docs don't move around too much?)

Disclaimer: I am no expert in concurrent design or in multithreading (different topics).

Comment: Thank you very much for your the time you took to write that out. I will keep your ideas in mind!

Answer (score 1):

If you split the input array in 4 equal subarrays for 4 threads, there is no guarantee that all threads finish simultaneously. You better put all data in a single queue and let all working threads feed from that common queue. Use thead-safe BlockingQueue implementations in order to not write low level synchronize/wait/notify code.

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned that dividing them like that forms assumptions  about order being irrelevant, and doesn't keep track at all of when the task is finished.

Answer (score 0):

From java 6 we have some handy utils for concurrency. You might want to consider using thread pools for cleaner implementation.

```
package com.threads;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class ParalleliseArrayConsumption {

    private int[] itemsToBeProcessed ;

    public ParalleliseArrayConsumption(int size){
        itemsToBeProcessed = new int[size];
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new ParalleliseArrayConsumption(32)).processUsers(4);

    }

    public void processUsers(int numOfWorkerThreads){
         ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfWorkerThreads);
         int chunk = itemsToBeProcessed.length/numOfWorkerThreads;
         int start = 0;
         List<Future> tasks = new ArrayList<Future>();
         for(int i=0;i<numOfWorkerThreads;i++){
             tasks.add(threadPool.submit(new WorkerThread(start, start+chunk)));
             start = start+chunk;
         }
             // join all worker threads to main thread
         for(Future f:tasks){
             try {
                f.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

        threadPool.shutdown();
        while(!threadPool.isTerminated()){
        }

    }

    private class WorkerThread implements Callable{

        private int startIndex;
        private int endIndex;

        public WorkerThread(int startIndex, int endIndex){
            this.startIndex = startIndex;
            this.endIndex = endIndex;
        }

        @Override
        public Object call() throws Exception {
            for(int currentUserIndex = startIndex;currentUserIndex<endIndex;currentUserIndex++){
                // process the user. Add your logic here
                System.out.println(currentUserIndex+" is the user being processed in thread " +Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
            return null;
        }       

    }

}
```